# How to add multiple html tag with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning jQuery I still have some problems with DOM.
I have one table that contains 3 rows and each row have 5 content. I need to add a forth row and its respective contents. Here's my code:

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
        <td>content</td>
      </tr>
    <table>
```

Above is the example How the table should be did
Below is my jQuery code

```js
    var arrayContent = ['Content1','Content2','Content3','Content4','Content5'];

    $('table').append(function(){
      return $('<tr>').append(function(){
         for(var i = 0; i < arrayContent.length; i++){
              return $('<td>')
         }
      })
    })
```

So this code abode only add one  tag and I need to add more to my page. Does anyone know how I can improve or suggest new way to do this?

Comment: The quotes in `arrayContent` are incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`// comments inline`

```js
var arrayContent = ['Content1','Content2','Content3','Content4','Content5'];

$('table').append(function(){
  return $('<tr>').append(function(){
    var td = '';  // create an empty string
    for(var i = 0; i < arrayContent.length; i++){
      td += '<td>' + arrayContent[i] + '</td>';  // compose the table data
    }
    return td;
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table></table>
```

Then, in your browser's web inspector, you will get:

[image]

Comment: @raul Why the td return was put out the loop? My thought was every return is to add a new td tag on the page. My logic was incorrect about this?

Comment: @ItaloLemos In your code, when you did `return $('<td>')`, the `for` loop doesnt go into the 2nd iteration since you are *returning* a value right there. However, In my code, I am returning it once all iterations are complete. :)

Comment: Yeah, make sense for me now. Thanks for share your knowledge. I appreciate .

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different approach:

```js
var arrayContent = ['Content1','Content2','Content3','Content4','Content5'];

function foo() {
 var dom = '<tr>';
 for (var i = 0; i < arrayContent.length; ++i)
  dom += '<td>' + arrayContent[i] + '</td>';
 dom += '</tr>';
 $('table').append(dom);
}

window.onload = foo; // here you can call the function on other events too, e.g. onclick
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```